# Sort ALV grid by inverted date

Tags: sorting, grid, abap, alv

I had a need to output TCURR table into ALV grid. All went fine but when user sorts table by "valid from" date (`GDATU`) strange things happened.
Sorting in ascending order behaves as sorting in descending order and vice versa. This is so because field `GDATU` contains date in inverted format and has domain `GDATU_INV` with the conversion routine `INVDT` which converts date on the fly. ALV grid shows the date correctly but sorting is done by inverted dates.

I solved it like this:

1. I declared table structure similar to `TCURR` and replaced `GDATU_INV` domain with simple `DATUM`.
2. I converted inverted dates into usual ones
3. I filled my table with the converted dates
4. After generating field catalog through FM `LVC_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE` according to `TCURR` structure I write to

CONVEXIT,
REF_TABLE,
DATATYPE,
DOMNAME

fields of the GDATU line values

'',
'',
'DATS',
'DATUM' respectively.

Is there more efficient and simple solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use your new structure in `LVC_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE`, in stead of using TCURR which would mean that you don't have to overwrite the settings in the field catalog after the fact.  But that's a pretty minor thing.

I don't think you had any choice but to use a structure with a data element that behaves the way you need it to.

Do look into the Simple ALV classes, though.  (`CL_SALV*`)  They are well documented and much easier to use than then now out-of-date ALV function modules. (Particularly generating the field catalog is a lot less hassle).